# Pointer to array of functions in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, definition

I have this type of definition

```
int (*af[10])(int , *a[10][10])(int,int)
```

and I had to "translate" it just like "this is pointer to function array size of 10" etc etc. I think that there is a mistake here, cause `*a[10][10]` doesn't have a definition type. Is this correct? Or this line can be translated properly?

Thanks in advance

---

Finally I found that the correct definition should be like this

```
int (*af[10])(int ,int (*a[10][10])(int,int))
```

which is correct and makes sense.

Comment: it's a syntax error because? missing definition type to the second array or?

Comment: Looks like a pointer to functions returning function pointers. Read it like "if I take af, give it an index from 0 to 9, dereference it, then call the result with two parameters of which one is an int and the other might be misspelled, and then call the result with two int parameters, then I get an int".

Comment: @yakamuki The type of `a` is incomplete.

Comment: For similiar questions, a look at http://cdecl.org might be helpful.

Comment: @glglgl cdecl.org thinks functions can return a function. For example, it will report `int (*af[10])(int *[10][10])(int,int);` as well-typed. This is misleading. Proper compilers are much more reliable in this case.

Comment: @leeduhem But compilers don't tell you what something might mean... Besides, you can see it in a way that cdecl tells what something would mean if it was valid.

Comment: @glglgl Yes, cdecl.org is helpful. My point is that you should not believe it blindly :-)

Comment: @leeduhem Ok, then it is fine. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a valid C declaration. First, the type of `a` is missing. But worse than that, it's as if `(*af[10])(int , *a[10][10])` was returning a function (which is impossible).

Maybe you meant:

```
int (*(*af[10])(int , int *a[10][10]))(int,int)
```

Which would make `af` an array of 10 pointers to function receiving `int` and an array of 10 arrays with 10 pointers to `int`, and returns a pointer to function receiving two `int`s and returning an `int`.

**EDIT:**

Looks like the correct line is:

```
int (*af[10])(int ,int (*a[10][10])(int,int))
```

This makes `af` an array of 10 pointers to function receiving 2 parameters and returning `int`. The first parameter is an `int`, and the second is a multi-dimensional array (10x10) or pointers to function receiving 2 `int`s and returning an `int`.

In the future, you might want to check out [cdecl.org](http://www.cdecl.org/) to confirm your guess.

Comment: yes, that's was what i thougt, but when i made a correction to these, i got a negative answer, as far this is correct syntax (according to them).

Comment: @yakamuki According to who?

Comment: i've been asked to translate this line for a course, that's why i'm so confused here..

Comment: @yakamuki If it was really like you showed, it's wrong. That's invalid C. Stuff it into a source file - it won't compile.

Comment: the funny thing is that i made the correction to the professor, he finally accepted this, but he kept asking to translate the wrong line..

Comment: finally i found it,  the correct line should be like this int (*af[10])(int ,int (*a[10][10])(int,int)).. that makes sense.. thanks a lot

Comment: @yakamuki Indeed, it does. I updated my answer with this. Have fun learning C declarations, they are beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `af` is actually an array:

```
af[10]
```

The array contains pointers:

```
*af[10]
```

Those are pointers to functions:

```
int (*af[10])(...)
```

And the argument list has a syntax error, probably the comma after `int` is there by mistake:

```
int (*af[10])(int *a[10][10])
```

And the rest of the line is rubbish.